# How to embed LaTeX keywords inside a LaTeX document using 'listings'

Tags: latex, tex, listings

I want to cite LaTeX code into my document but how do I embed the keywords "\begin{lstlisting}" and "\end{lstlisting}" correctly?

CODE BELOW DOES NOT WORK (obviously):

```
\lstset{language=TeX, basicstyle=\footnotesize, numbers=left, numberstyle=\tiny, frame=single}

\begin{lstlisting}

\begin{lstlisting}          % this is code

place your source code here % this is code

\end{lstlisting}            % this is code

\end{lstlisting}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you have `\usepackage{listings}` in your preamble? If so, it should work. `TeX` is a supported language.

Here's a minimal example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\begin{document}
  This is a StackOverflow test file.\\
  To use \texttt{lstlisting}, include this in the preamble:
  \begin{lstlisting}
    \usepackage{listings}
  \end{lstlisting}
  Hope that helped :)
\end{document}
```

which compiles to

[image]

**EDIT**

To quote commands from the listings package (actually, only for `\end{lstlisting}`), escape to latex to print the `\` character and you're all set. In the following, I've defined `@` as the escape character and everything within two `@` symbols is typeset in LaTeX. So here, I've input the `\` using LaTeX and the rest within `lstlisting` and the `\end{...}` sequence is not interpreted as a closing the environment.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\begin{document}
This is a StackOverflow test file.\\
Use escape characters to escape to \LaTeX 
\lstset{escapechar=\@}
\begin{lstlisting}
  \begin{lstlisting}
      some code here
  @\textbackslash@end{lstlisting}
\end{lstlisting}
Hope that helped :)
\end{document}
```

The output is

[image]

Comment: Yes I do, and I know TeX is supported.  Just can't seem to cite LaTeX code.  I am trying the \lstnewenvironment tip above.

Comment: @nerd.brazil: see my minimal example. it compiles fine on my machine. If you list the commands that didn't work, I can try to see if it compiles on mine.

Comment: Ok.  I got that too.  Now try quoting '\begin{lstlisting}' and '\end{lstlisting}'.

Comment: Just a minor point: escaping to latex to print the '\' character breaks the listings keyword highlight for '\end'. If I don't use keyword highlight, then this method is quite simple and elegant.

Comment: In your highlighting scheme, are the curly braces the default color or are they colored too? If default, then instead of escaping the \, you can escape the last `}` as `@\}@`. The point is, you just need to escape something so that the entire thing is not interpreted. So it can be any letter within `lstlisting` too. Simply choose whichever one is the default color. I would argue that this is better, as with defining new environments, the problem still exists if you need to enter the `\end` sequence for that environment. Whereas here, you have more control over it.

Comment: Gotcha! This solves all my problems and is now my preferred solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

can you use a verbatim block?

\begin{verbatim}

\begin{lstlisting} % this is code

place your source code here % this is code

\end{lstlisting} % this is code

\end{verbatim}

Comment: I can but I would lose the line numbering and frame, and possibly keyword highlight as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
\lstnewenvironment{OtherListing}
    {}
    {}
```

to create a new envirnment that behaves just list `lstlisting`, and `\end{lstlisting}` should not be forbidden in it.